# How to access a KVM virtual-machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, virtualization, virt-manager

I've created a KVM VM using `virt-install`. There is an image file in the directory `/ssd/kvms`.

How do I access the virtual machine and turn it on? Do I need to assign an IP address, and if so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If it's for the same architecture, you can start it with something like

```
kvm -cpu host -m 1024 -hda /ssd/kvms/my-image.bin
```

Options

```
-cpu host
```

means use same CPU as host machine

```
-m 1024
```

use 1GB main memory

```
-hda /ssd/kvms/my-image.bin
```

this image is my first hard disk

There are many more options listed in [man kvm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/qemu-kvm).

Answer (score 1):

If you used virt-install, you're using libvirt, and you can use virt-manager to manage and view the VM.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager.py", line 383, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager.py", line 286, in main
    raise gtk_error
RuntimeError: could not open display

Comment: I got the above error after installing virt-manager using yum and starting it. Is there any way to access SSH of the VM without using virt-manager? Must I assign it an IP?>

Comment: For your first question, you need an X display (e.g. `ssh -X` to your server) to run virt-manager.  For the second question, yes, SSH uses the network and so you need an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

What distro are you using?
Debian? Centos? Arch? Ubuntu? Suse?

I can recommend http://virt-manager.org/   (older versions can be found in your package manager at your distribution of linux)
Very good tutorial can be found here: http://virt-tools.org/learning/start-install-with-virt-manager/

All basic operations with KVM can very easily be done with virt-manager. It is easy, fast and quiet safe for newbies.

All others possibilities how to control KVM can be found here: linux-kvm.org/page/Management_Tools

But i tried some of them and did not working.